# Can you have too many polygons before retopology?

Tags: modeling, topology, polycount

When doing a high poly model before retopology can you still make a model with too many polygons?

Comment: What do you mean by "too many polygons"?

Comment: I read from a forum that this person did retopo on a mid poly mesh instead of high poly to perserve some base topology or something, but then the majority answered they'd retopo on a high poly mesh. So based on that I'm wondering if there is any reason to keep the polycount down when your gonna do retopology on it later? @mugnozzo

Comment: IMO, You _always_ want to  keep the poly count at the minimum that resolves the maximum the level of detail you need, not only considering the model itself, but also the maximum texture map size and the highest resolution at which it might ever be displayed, if for no other reason than to make sure your (or someone else's) hardware can cope with it.